# want to get a UIElement's Size

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, size

I want to get a `UIElement`'s `Size`, but when I use the `DesiredSize` or `RenderSize` property, it always return {0,0}. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the element's `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties. They'll only have values after the element has been rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem happens because while inside the constructor, you do not have rendered elements. The elements are initialized yes, but they have not been rendered yet, therefore the value returned when you call `ActualHeight` or `ActualWidth` is 0 and Height and Width is NaN (Not a Number).

If you ask for the same information after the constructor has finished (for example during the Loaded event for the Window) you will receive that information.